# How to set a String to \

Tags: string

I want to set a string to \ because I want to make a code which should take only a line from the text the user typed into an UITextView. And a for loop should detect \n.

But if I say "" Xcode says: "Unterminated string literal" Until I write """
but then the String only takes ".
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is used as an escape character. It is used to escape special characters that you would not usually be able to use within the string.
For example you cannot use `"` in a string because it is the character used to start and end the string.
If you type `"\""` then the 2nd `"` is escaped and will be seen inside the string.

To use `\` in a string, you have to escape it as well.

So the solution is to type `\\`.